# Microsoft Teams custom website tab retrieve information about the Team and corresponding SharePoint site

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-teams

I'm looking for a way to access the corresponding Microsoft Team and SharePoint site that is created from a custom website tab.  So what I have is a custom website tab added to a Microsoft Teams site.  This tab is a website tab and is pointing to the custom website app that I'm building.

What I want to do is from within the custom website I want to be able to access the corresponding SharePoint site that was created from the Microsoft Team and then I want to be able to use the SharePoint client object model to interact with the document library.

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to have your tab / web app provide an auth flow, and ask your user to grant access to the Graph APIs, which can be used to access that content.

Comment: Can you provide an example or documentation that shows the details about this. Thanks